# unauthorized page configuration in web.xml

Tags: java, security, web

Is there unauthorized page configuration in web.xml so that it can return a page instead of "Error 403--Forbidden".

We know that in  web.xml, we can have  error.jsp like following to guide user to another page.

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Is there any similar things if a user is authenticated but not listed in the users which is used to protect current page by using security-constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<error-page>
    <!-- Forbidden directory listing -->
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/general-error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Yes. This seems to be the direct way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do a Filter, check this out: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_writing_filters.htm

Comment: It can also work I think. But I don't want to break the security setting. If we do it in this way, we will check user group or role infor by ourself.